# Key Binding not working, action not performed

Tags: java, swing, key, action

I'm just trying to learn how the key binders work, and it seems I've misunderstood something from the Java tutorials. This is the code:

```
public class KeyBinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //making frame and label to update when "g" key is pressed.

        JLabel keybinderTestLabel;

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(300,75);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        keybinderTestLabel = new JLabel("Press the 'g' key to test the key binder.");
        mainFrame.add(keybinderTestLabel);

        Action gPressed = new AbstractAction(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keybinderTestLabel.setText("Key Binding Successful.");
                System.out.println("Key Binding Successful.");
                //Testing to see if the key binding was successful.
            }

        };


        keybinderTestLabel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("g"), "gPressed");
        keybinderTestLabel.getActionMap().put("gPressed", gPressed);
        /*
         * from my understanding, these two lines map the KeyStroke event of the g key
         * to the action name "gpressed", then map the action name "gpressed" to the action
         * gpressed.
         * 
         */
    }

}
```

From what I understand, I mapped the g keystroke to the action name "gPressed", then mapped that to the action `gPressed`. For some reason though, when I run the program, pressing the g key does not update the text label. What's the issue here? is the "g" keystroke not actually mapped to the g key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from the JavaDocs

> `public final InputMap getInputMap()` 
>   Returns the `InputMap` that is used
>   when the component has focus. This is convenience method for
>   `getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED)`.

Since `JLabel` is not focusable, this will never work, instead, you need to supply a different focus condition, for example...

```
keybinderTestLabel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW). //...
```

Also, and this is a personal preference... `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("g")` using `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke` like this can be problematic as the `String` you supply needs be very precise in it's meaning, and I can never remember exactly how it should work (and it's not overly documented).

If the first suggestion fails to fix the issue, also try using `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0)` instead

Comment: (1+) `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("g")` - won't work.  If you want to use a String, you can use: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("G")`. If will register a binding for pressing the "g" on the keyboard. When you use a string you basically take the text after the KeyEvent.VK_???. So you could also use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER")` to listen for the "Enter" key. Or easier to understand is to use a character parameter: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('g')`,

Comment: Ah thanks! But with the getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_G, 0), what is the 0 parameter doing?

Comment: @Psear It’s the modifier (ie shift/alt/control)